# How do I compare the widths of two different fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I would like to see numerical values of how different the character widths of strings taken from two different fonts MS Gothic and Liberation Mono are.

So I used FontForge's metrics, which worked differently than I expected.

Since the "あ" in MS Gothic is larger than the "=" in Liberation Mono, I expected the "幅" column value for character width to be larger in MS Gothic. However, this was not the case, and in fact the "=" was **1229** and the "あ" was **256**. However, as you can see from the screenshot, "あ" is definitely larger than "=". How can I get a character width that will give me the result I expect?

[image: Image of FontForge unexpected results]